# Which way is preferred to call copy constructor for a class?

Tags: c++, copy-constructor

Below is sample class written with copy constructor in c++.

```
class Foo {
public:
    Foo()   { std::cout << "Foo::Foo\n";}
    ~Foo()   { std::cout << "Foo::Foo\n";}
    Foo(const Foo& rhs) {
        std::cout << "cctor\n";
    }

    Foo& operator=(const Foo& rhs) {
        if (&rhs == this) return *this;
        std::cout << " operator =\n";
        return *this;
    }

    void bar() { std::cout << "Foo::bar\n";}
};
```

Now we can write in couple of ways which would invoke copy constructor of the class.

```
Foo x;
Foo y;
Foo z = x;     // This calls copy constructor
Foo a(z);      // This also calls copy constructor
```

So **out of two style which one is preferred** and is there any explanation for that?. Or these two are more of style preference of developer.

Comment: There are huge tomes written on initialization in C++, but for regular usage, you probably won't notice any difference. Personally, I'd prefer `Foo z = x;` or uniform initialization `Foo a{z};`.

Comment: `Foo z = x;` is copy initialization vs `Foo A(z);` is direct initialization. If you understand the difference between the two, you will be able to decide which is suitable in which situation. **There is no one fits all** in c++.

Comment: The question is deeper than you might think. Please start with this talk: https://youtu.be/ZfP4VAK21zc

Comment: The first `Foo(const Foo& rhs)` is the copy constructor, however the second `Foo& operator=(const Foo& rhs)` is a copy assignment. There is no right or wrong here, it all depends on the context.
Do note that for most classes, the ones that do not manage non-copyable things, you can leverage the rule of [zero/three/five](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three).

Comment: @BrunoHendrickx -- your comment is correct, but note that there are no assignments in the code in the question. `Foo z = x;` constructs an object, so it uses the copy constructor. It does not use the assignment operator, even though it has that `=` sign.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> out of two style which one is preferred

`Foo z = x;` is copy initialization vs `Foo A(z);` is direct initialization. If you understand the difference between the two, you will be able to decide which is suitable in which situation. **There is no one fits all** in c++. Asking which is preferred assumes that one of them is "always" preferred over the other, which is not the case in reality. Depending on the context one might be preferred over the other.

For example, direct initialization would work even when the copy constructor is **explicit** while copy initialization would not work there. In *implicit conversions* where copy initialization is performed, the explicit copy ctor won't be used.